# Simple regexp match

Tags: java, regex

What's the correct regex to match such set `[1] [2] [3] [4] [23]` - where numbers are inside the brackets. (I need to get the brackets though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex \[[0-9]+\] will match anything like '[1]', '[2]', '[678]'. A more precise regex, which catches one or more of these patterns in sequence, is:

((\[[0-9]+\])( |$))+

Comment: `\[\d+\]( |$)*` : better remove not necessary subgroups '()'

Comment: This pattern doesn't do the same job as mine, which matches many \\[[0-9]\\]+ in sequence separated by spaces and followed by a EoL character. So, the best equivalent is (\\[[0-9]+\\]( |$))+

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Java regex, but if it's PCRE, I think it should be:

```
/(\[\d+\])/
```

I wasn't exactly sure if you need the brackets in the match, but if you don't, I think you could use

```
/\[(\d+)\]/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to capture any of the numbers the following expression will match a string with that pattern:

> `(?:\[\d+\]\s?)+`

Comment: What if it's in the text. Like in any wiki page (or almost any). And I need to match them even if it's like *word[2] word*?

Comment: @den-javamaniac: I guess I don't really understand what you want to match. Do you want to know if any of the text contains a wiki link? Do you want to capture any wiki links in a big block of text?

Comment: den-javamaniac explicitly states that brackets need to get captured, and why are you assuming that the pattern doesn't need to be captured?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\[\\d+\\])\\s*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("[1] [2] [3] [4] [23]");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("match = " + matcher.group(1));
}
```